# Jquery Incompatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 test pages, http://www.northstardata.com/testing/index3.html and http://www.northstardata.com/testing/index4.html. Index3 works fine, index4 does not. They are the same with the exception that in index4.html, I have the js_extra.js commented out. This is a stripped down page and I need all the linked js items.

When I do load index4, and roll over the menu's in FF, I get "error in parsing value for 'background-position'. Declaration dropped. In IE it gives a javascript error and says invalid argument.

Can someone please tell me what the incompatibility is?

Comment: I'm simply trying to open Index4 in Safari and it's taking FOREVER.  _"Failed to load resource, timed out"_ on three of your JavaScript files.  You also have a TypeError on `ui.slider.js`

Comment: It just started working.  Either you changed something or your hosting server is flaking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "js_extra.js" file appears to be a really old version of jQuery. It should not be included with the other (also old) version of jQuery you're including.

Also, "js_extra.js" is not commented out in your "index4" page, but it is commented out in "index3".  That's probably why it works properly.

Comment: Sorry, I had them backwards. The slider stuff will not work without the js_extra.js.  Yes, I have isolated it to that file.  Is there a way to use both?  I am thinking they are redefining the $ variable or fighting over it.  I know you can use the noconflict method, but I am not sure how I would use this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion would honestly be to figure out a way to avoid using a 3-year-old version of jQuery.  A plugin that hasn't been updated to work with new versions of the library is going to be a permanent headache.